# pyo3: Passing a reference of Rust's Self into a method of Self with attribute `#[classmethod]`

Tags: python, rust, pyo3, python-bindings

Context of my question:

In [pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#classes-with-__get_validators__)'s, you can define a `CustomType`, which is any python class with the following class method named `__get_validators__(cls)` defined. The objective is to have pydantic validate the input to the initialization of the `CustomType` instance.

```
class CustomType:

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate_func_one
```

I am attempting to create a struct in Rust, mapping it to Python class using the familiar attribute macro `#[pyclass]`. My objective is to create from Rust, a Python class that is compatible with pydantic validation scheme, e.g. having the `classmethod(__get_validators__)` defined.

Here is my attempt:

```
#[pyclass(name = "MyPythonClass")]
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct PyClass {
    pub rust_object: MyRustStruct,
}
```

The implementation of `PyClass` is as follows:

```
#[pymethods]
impl PyClass {
    #[new]
    fn new(string: String) -> PyResult<PyClass > {
        Ok(PyClass {
            rust_object: MyRustStruct::new(string).unwrap(),
        })
    }

    // intended to be the `cls.validate` function which is yielded
    fn __call__(_cls: &PyType, v: &PyString, _values: &PyDict) -> PyResult<PyClass> {
        let v: &str = v.extract()?;
        Ok(PyClass{
            // PyClass::new does all the validations required in rust
            rust_object: PyClass::new(v).unwrap(),
        })
    }

    #[classmethod] // not sure how to write this...
    fn __get_validator__(_cls: &PyType) -> PyResult<PyClassContainer> {
      Ok(Self::get_container())
    }
```

`PyClass` is a wrapper over the underlying Rust struct `MyRustStruct`, such that `MyRustStruct` can be used for other purposes, e.g. to build a binary etc. This is standard practice.

To be able to `yield`, I would need two things: first, a struct that is an `Iterator` in rust and last, that `struct` has to implement

First:

```
#[pyclass(name = "PyClassContainer")]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct PyClassContainer{
    iter: Vec<PyClass>,
}
```

To trivially 'implement' the rust `Iterator` trait, I dump the `PyClass` object into a `Vector`.

Then lastly, for the implementations of `__iter__` and `__next__` of `PyClassContainer`:

```
#[pymethods]
impl PyClassContainer{

    fn __iter__(slf: PyRef<'_, Self>) -> PyResult<Py<PyClassContainer>> {
        let iter = PyClassContainer{
            iter: slf.iter.clone().into_iter(),
        };
        Py::new(slf.py(), iter)
    }

    // to use `yield`, the `__next__` method has to return an `IterNextOutput<T, U>` enum
    // https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/pyclass/enum.IterNextOutput.html
    fn __next__(slf: PyRef<'_, Self>) -> IterNextOutput<Result<PyClass, &'static str>, PyErr> {
        match self.iter.into_iter() {
            Some(Ok(item)) => IterNextOutput::Yield(Ok(item)),
            Some(Err(err)) => IterNextOutput::Return(PyStopIteration::new_err(err)),
    }
  }
}
```

My intent is to have `__next__` to 'yield' `Ok(item)` from the `.iter` field of `PyClassContainer` which will return me an instance of the python object of type `PyClass` when `PyClass.__get_validator__` is called.

However, the signature of attribute macro [`#[classmethod]`](https://pyo3.rs/v0.18.1/class#class-methods) does not allow the passing in of a reference of `self`, which makes it impossible for me to 'clone' the fields that are already available in `self`.

Comment: The entire thing seems confused. Why are you trying to yield "an instance of the python object" when `__get_validators__` clearly returns an iterable of *callables*, which get chained to ultimately yield a value? I also fail to see where and why you'd "clone" (whatever that means) fields available in `self`: there is no self at this point from what I understand.

Comment: And the intentions declared on `__call__` don't seem to make any sense, that's an instance method, which is used to make instances callable. The `__call__` of a class is its constructor, you can't override that (well you can but you have to use the metaclass, and it substitutes the entire initialisation protocol).

Comment: Also from the pydantic documentation it looks a bit like it *really* wants its validators to be classmethod, *and* will introspect the signature to know what to pass in (not unlike e.g. pytest test functions).

Comment: Yes, I managed to make some progress but stuck at the introspection of the signature of the callable yielded by `__get_validators__`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574260/pyo3-troubles-with-inspect-signature-method You can read more about it here.